# Android: Creating selectable button bar

Tags: android, layout

I am struggling to create a bar, where the user would be able to select an option from a list of buttons, that are contained within a horizontal linear layout, where each of them represent a select able option.

Below is what i am trying to replicate.

| selected | gray | gray | gray |

What control's should i be using, and how would i configure it, so that only one option may be selected at a given time?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: use radio-group and put 4 radio-buttons in it. It will display 1 selected at a time.Or u can make other button disable when user selects one of them.

Comment: I was thinking of using this way to, but can i change the look of the radio buttons to look like actual buttons?

Comment: yes u can easily customize radio buttons.

Comment: Thanks i explored customizing the radio buttons, works perfectly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Method 1**

you can use radio-group and put 4 radio-buttons in it. 
It will display 1 selected at a time.You can also easily customize the radio buttons.

**Or**

**Method 2**

just use 4 buttons and you can make other buttons disable when user selects one of them.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simply go with buttons, using Button.setEnabled(boolean). Think you can just change others state basing on the selected one.